# Error redondeo de valor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy realizando un programa de calculos de valores de un producto, y tengo un error a la hora de realizar el calculo inicial, y es que no me redondea el valor del producto si por ejemplo pongo "1.999999", no me lo coloca como 2, sino que me sale con esos decimales a pesar de que luego al realizar el calculo final de la factura y la base imponible, me lo pone bien, he intentado subsanarlo con un **$("#total-linea").val($valorPrecioUnitario - $valorDescuento).toFixed(2);**, pero no se si es que o lo estoy poniendo mal o no se que es lo que ocurre que porque no me lo redondea. Adjunto una imagen para que veais a lo que me refiero y mi codigo a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(document).on('click', '#agregarLinea', function (event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        //Especificamos los valores que vamos a tomar
        $valorProducto = $("#producto").val();
        $valorCantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
        $valorPrecioUnitario = $("#precio-unitario").val();
        $valorDescuento = $("#descuento").val();
        $valorTotal = $("#total-linea").val();
        

        //insertamos los contenidos
        $("tbody").append("<tr class='info'>"
            + "<td> " + $valorProducto + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorCantidad'> " + $valorCantidad + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorPrecioUnitario'> " + $valorPrecioUnitario + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorDescuento'> " + $valorDescuento + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorTotal'> " + $valorTotal + " </td>"
            + "<td> <button type'button' class='borrar btn-success'> Borrar </button>"
            + "</tr>"
        );
        //Limpiamos los valores al agregar (botón)
        $("#producto").val("");
        $("#cantidad").val("");
        $("#precio-unitario").val("");
        $("#descuento").val("");
        $("#total").val("");

        //CALCULAR EL TOTAL
        //base imponible es 0 y se suma al total que inicialmente es 0, hasta que metamos un costo
        $cantidadActualizada = parseFloat($("#base-imponible").text()) + parseFloat($valorTotal);
        $("#base-imponible").text(parseFloat($cantidadActualizada).toFixed(2));
        //calculamos el iva y lo sumamos a la factura del producto/s
        $iva = ($cantidadActualizada * 1.21) - $cantidadActualizada;
        let total_iva=parseFloat($iva).toFixed(2);
        $("#iva").html(total_iva<0?0:total_iva);
        $totalFact = $cantidadActualizada + $iva;
        $("span#total").text(parseFloat($totalFact).toFixed(2));
        $('#total-linea').val($valorTotal.toFixed(2));
        
        //establecemos la fecha actual de las compras
        let date = new Date();
        let time = "Articulo: " + $valorProducto + " añadido el "
            + date.getUTCDate() + "/"
            + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/"
            + date.getUTCFullYear() + " a las "
            + date.getHours() + ":"
            + date.getMinutes() + ":"
            + date.getSeconds();
        $(".container").append("<p>" + time + "</p>");


    });

    /*BORRAR FILA*/
    //agregamos evento click al botón borrar
    $(document).on('click', ".borrar", function () {
        $valor = $(this).parent().siblings(".valorTotal").text();
        //restamos los valores de cada apartado para dejarlo todo de vuelta a 0
        $cantidadActualizada = parseFloat($("#base-imponible").text()) - parseFloat($valor);
        let total_base=parseFloat($cantidadActualizada).toFixed(2);
        //impedimos que baje a menos de 0
        $("#base-imponible").html(total_base<0?0:total_base);
        $iva = ($cantidadActualizada * 1.21) - $cantidadActualizada;
        let total_iva=parseFloat($iva).toFixed(2);
        //impedimos que baje a menos de 0
        $("#iva").html(total_iva<0.001?0:total_iva);
        //igualamos a 0 la factura
        $totalFact = $cantidadActualizada + $iva;
        let total_mostrar=parseFloat($totalFact).toFixed(2);
        $("span#total").html(total_mostrar<0?0:total_mostrar);
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

    //ESTABLECEMOS DESCUENTO A UN PRODUCTO
    $(document).on('mouseout', "#descuento, #precio-unitario", function () 
    {
        //Tomamos cada uno de los valores de cada celda
        $valorCantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
        $valorPrecioUnitario = $("#precio-unitario").val();
        //aplicamos el descuento
        $valorDescuento = $("#descuento").val();
        //calculamos
        $("#total-linea").val($valorCantidad * $valorPrecioUnitario * (1 - $valorDescuento / 100));
        $("#total-linea").val($valorPrecioUnitario - $valorDescuento).toFixed(2);
    });

    //APLICAMOS EL DESCUENTO A TODAS LAS FILAS
    $(document).on('click', "#aplicarDescuento", function (event) 
    {event.preventDefault();
        //tomamos el valor del descuento
        $descuentoLineas = $("#descuento-lineas").val();
        //leemos el valor aplicado
        $(".valorDescuento").text($descuentoLineas);

        //Calculamos el descuento
        $(".info").each(function () {
            //buscamos y leemos
            $valorCantidad = $(this).find(".valorCantidad").text();
            $valorPrecioUnitario = $(this).find(".valorPrecioUnitario").text();
            //calculamos el descuento
            $valorTotal = parseFloat($valorCantidad) * parseFloat($valorPrecioUnitario) * (1 - parseFloat($descuentoLineas) / 100);
            $(this).children('.valorTotal').text($valorTotal);
        });
        $refreshAmount = 0;
        $iva = 0;
        $('.valorTotal').each(function () {
            $parse = parseFloat($(this).text());
            $refreshAmount += $parse;
            let total_base=parseFloat($refreshAmount).toFixed(2);
            $("#base-imponible").html(total_base<0?0:total_base);
    
        });
        $iva = ($refreshAmount * 1.21) - $refreshAmount;
        let total_iva=parseFloat($iva).toFixed(2);
        $("#iva").html(total_iva<0?0:total_iva);
        $totalFact = $refreshAmount + $iva;

        let total_mostrar=parseFloat($totalFact).toFixed(2);
        $("span#total").html(total_mostrar<0?0:total_mostrar);

    });
    
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title> DWC </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mt-5">
                    <h3>Introducción de productos en la factura</h3>
                    <table class="table table-striped mt-4">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                                <th>Precio unitario</th>
                                <th>Descuento (%)</th>
                                <th>Precio total</th>
                                <th>Opciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="producto" id="producto" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="precio-unitario" id="precio-unitario" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="descuento" id="descuento" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="total-linea" id="total-linea" readonly /></td>
                                <td><a href="" id="agregarLinea" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-right" colspan="4">Base imponible</td>
                                <td class="text-right"><span id="base-imponible">0</span>€</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-right" colspan="4" data-iva="0.21">IVA 21%</td>
                                <td class="text-right"><span id="iva">0</span>€</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="descuento-lineas" id="descuento-lineas" placeholder="%" /></td>
                                <td colspan="2"><a href="" id="aplicarDescuento" class="btn btn-info">Aplicar descuento a todas las líneas</a></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><strong>Total factura</strong></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><strong><span id="total">0</span>€</strong></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src='facturas.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El **toFixed** te ordena los decimales

Si usas **toFixed(2)** signfica que un **2** será **2.00**
o si un **1.99999** sera **2.00**

Ahora si deseas que solo sea un número usando el *toFixed* pero sin valor

Ejemplo:

```js
var valor=1.999999;

//Valor Con Decimales
console.log(valor.toFixed(2));


//Valor Sin Decimales
console.log(valor.toFixed());
```

El valor que coloques dentro del **toFixed(*valor*)** será la cantidad de decimales.

Comment: Sisi, comprendo como funciona el Tofixed, sin embargo lo que no logro conseguir es que me arregle esa cantidad de decimales que me sale aun teniendo el Tofixed colocado.

Comment: Ok, coloca tu script aca https://jsfiddle.net/ para verlo y poder editarlo

Comment: ¡Claro! https://jsfiddle.net/daqszy2f/

Comment: El error se produce con que valores específicamente? para replicar exacto como tu

Comment: Prueba esta version a ver si es lo que buscas https://jsfiddle.net/c8rLxq15/

Comment: Justo te estaba respondiendo, pero vaya, si era justo eso lo que quería conseguir, muchas gracias de nuevo, me ayudaste también la ultima vez :)!

Comment: Si me di cuenta recién jajajaja Saludos!

Comment: Buenas, disculpa de nuevo, me acabo de dar cuenta de una cosa recien, y es que he visto que una vez agregado el precio unitario por ejemplo 1.99999 me lo redondea perfectamente a 2.00, pero luego al aplicar precio descuento por ejemplo 1, me sale otro decimal gigantesco, cosa extraña porque tengo los toFixed(2) también colocados.

Comment: Listo, https://jsfiddle.net/1c7myapx/1/ verifica

Comment: No D: , de hecho ahora cuando pongo en descuento 1, si el precio que puse es 2, hace como que me lo resta en 1, y en el aplicar descuento si pongo muchos decimales en el precio del producto, me saca un descuento con muchos decimales también

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132334/discussion-between-josue-vargas-and-puntoycoma).